# Evaluate an integral along a semicircle.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let $\gamma$ be the semicircle $[-R,R]\cup\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=R\ and\ Im{z}>0\}$ traced in the positive direction, and let $R>1$.  Evaluate
$$\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{(z^2+1)^2}.$$

I want to say that since neither of the poles of the function $f(z):=1/(z^2+1)^2$, namely $i$ and $-i$, are inside the semicircle, we can use the General Closed Curve Theorem here to deduce that the value of the integral is zero.  Or am I missing something, and need to use Residue Theorem?

Comment: You sure that $i$ isn't inside?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo.  It should be $R<1$.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case the answer is 0, as you suggested.

Comment: But it's not a closed curve.

Comment: @zhw.: Why not? And by the way, *nonremovable*, write $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ (`$\operatorname{Im}(z)$`) or at least $Im(z)$, since $Imz$ looks like a product of $I,m,z$.

Comment: Sorry, I saw semicircle and went to work.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's theorem, it equals $-\int_{-R}^R \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2}.$ We're now back in calculus, and I'm getting $-(\arctan R +\frac{R}{1+R^2})$ for the answer (better check that).

Comment: His 'semicircle' includes the diameter.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Sorry, about that. I'll let it stand.